# How to compare 1 word versus many and output a list of levenshtein scores

Tags: php, arrays, list, levenshtein-distance

I have a form where I can input two words then compare the levenshtein score, that works fine.

I want to be able to compare 1 word with a string of words delimited by ", ". The whole lot then needs to echo out. Here's what I have so far:

```
Levenstein for <b><?php echo $_POST["source"]; ?></b> and <b><?php echo $_POST["target"]; ?></b>:

<?php
$string5 = $_POST["source"];
$string6 = $_POST["target"];
$array6 = explode(', ',$string6); 
    
echo levenshtein("$string5","$array6");
?>
```

Comment: The follow up questions to this question: [Sort array of values by their levenshtein distance from a comparison string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12736633/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You'd use a `foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) (a `for` loop would be fine too). Try:

```
Levenstien for <b><?php echo $_POST["source"]; ?></b> and <b><?php echo $_POST["target"]; ?></b>:

<?php
$string5 = $_POST["source"];
$string6 = $_POST["target"];
$array6 = explode(', ',$string6); 

foreach ($array6 as $derp)
{
    echo $string5, "/", $derp, ": ", levenshtein($string5, $derp), "<br>";
}

?>
```

To output in order by score, use this:

```
Levenstien for <b><?php echo $_POST["source"]; ?></b> and <b><?php echo $_POST["target"]; ?></b>:

<?php
$string5 = $_POST["source"];
$string6 = $_POST["target"];
$array6 = array_map('trim', explode(',',$string6));
$doop = array();

foreach ($array6 as $derp)
{
    doop[$derp] = levenshtein($string5, $derp);
}

arsort($doop); // sorts highest element first

foreach ($words as $key => $value)
{
    echo sprintf('%s / %s: %s<br />', $string5, $key, $value);
}

?>
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've written anything in php.  I'm pretty sure this is syntactically correct though.

Comment: That is absolutely amazing!!! Can I output that list from smaller to larger levenstien scores?

Comment: I don't think that worked I get a server error? Thank you for your help it is really, really appreciated

Comment: I patched in your edit.  Using array_flip isn't required so I skipped it.  Review the editing guidelines to ensure your edits are not rejected in the future.