# Sort array of values by their levenshtein distance from a comparison string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, levenshtein-distance

I have a form that compares 1 word with many and outputs a list of levenshtein scores. How can I get those scores so they list in order, smallest levenshtein score 1st:

```
$string5 = $_POST["singleword"];
$string6 = $_POST["manywords"];
$array6 = explode(', ',$string6); 

foreach ($array6 as $derp)
{
    echo $string5, "/", $derp, ": ", levenshtein($string5, $derp), "<br>";
}
```

The current list output would be like this:

```
apple/mango: 5
apple/peach: 5
apple/toothpaste: 8
apple/apes: 3
```

I want it to be like this:

```
apple/apes: 3
apple/mango: 5
apple/peach: 5
apple/toothpaste: 8
```

Comment: I know it has something to do with arsort but I can't figure out how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string5 = $_POST["singleword"];
$string6 = $_POST["manywords"];

$words = array_flip(array_map('trim', explode(',', $string6)));

foreach ($words as $key => $value)
{
    $words[$key] = levenshtein($string5, $key);
}

asort($words);

foreach ($words as $key => $value)
{
    printf('%s / %s: %s<br />', $string5, $key, $value);
}
```

Comment: that wierd it works for me to with $string5 = 'carrrot'; then breaks with $string5 = $_POST["singleword"];

Comment: is it the comma? Sorry my fault!!! Your codes perfect I wasnt inputting commas in my list just using a space. Thank you so very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think I recommend populating an array of arrays then sorting that.  If all subarrays have the same size, then the first elements will be sorted and the second elements used to break any ties.  This will effectively create payload sorted by levenshtein ASC, then value ASC.  One advantage of this script is that the original array is modified instead of populating a new array.  Also, no flipping is needed since no key comparisons are made.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dCipR))

```
$needle = 'apple';
$haystack = explode(', ', 'mango, peach, toothpaste, apes');

foreach ($haystack as &$v) {
    $v = [levenshtein($needle, $v), $v];
}
sort($haystack);

foreach ($haystack as [$lev, $h]) {
    echo "$needle/$h: $lev\n";
}
```